# Github repo not completely uploading or uploading a previous version

Tags: git, github

I am using the following commands to update my github repo from the command line:

$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/samrao2/manager-4.git
$ git push -u origin master

I get the following success message from the CLI:

"Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Everything up-to-date:

However, the files are not updating correctly on github:

What am i doing wrong?

On local repo:

```
SRC/App.js:

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import firebase from 'firebase';
//reduxthnunk is helping us with aync operations, its a middlware
//to help with this middleware we need a ahelper from Redux library
//
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './reducers';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';


class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const config = {
    apiKey: 'AIzaSyCCEY-CD1iSpSowupPZJcSuHEQ_yLvVzhg',
    authDomain: 'manager-2714d.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://manager-2714d.firebaseio.com',
    projectId: 'manager-2714d',
    storageBucket: 'manager-2714d.appspot.com',
    messagingSenderId: '191493388327'
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  }
  render() {
    const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
    return (
          <Provider store={store}>
          <LoginForm />
        </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Same file in GITHUB repo:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import firebase from 'firebase';
//reduxthnunk is helping us with aync operations, its a middlware
//to help with this middleware we need a ahelper from Redux library
//
import Reduxthunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './reducers';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';


class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const config = {
    apiKey: 'AIzaSyCCEY-CD1iSpSowupPZJcSuHEQ_yLvVzhg',
    authDomain: 'manager-2714d.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://manager-2714d.firebaseio.com',
    projectId: 'manager-2714d',
    storageBucket: 'manager-2714d.appspot.com',
    messagingSenderId: '191493388327'
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  }

  render() {
    return (
          <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
          <LoginForm />
        </Provider>
      );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Did you add and commit your files before pushing? Using `git add .` and `git commit -m "commit message`.

Comment: Yes I did do that